# Relevance of a secondary extra temporary variable when tring to delete a node from linked list

Tags: c, function, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

**Confused with free(tmp)  function**

I am trying to understand the working of deletion function of a node from a singly linked list

Why can i replace these 2 lines

```
 tmp=q->link;
 q->link=tmp->link;
```

with

```
 q->link=q->link->link;
```

I have the function as

```
del(int data){
struct node *tmp,*q;

if(start->info ==data){
tmp=start;
start=start->link;
free(tmp);
return;

}

q=start;


deletion in between
while(q->link->link!=NULL){

if(q->link->info==data)
{
/_______________________________/

tmp=q->link;

q->link=tmp->link;

free(tmp);
/_______________________________/

return;
}

q=q->link;
}

if(q->link->info==data){
tmp=q->link;
q->link=tmp->link;
free(tmp);


return;
}
printf("Element %d not found",data);
}
```

This is program that works fine {taken from a text book}

But my doubt is why cant i do `q->link=q->link->link;`when trying to delete a node ..by substituiting this code in between the place marked as `/---------------------/`

I accept the fact that you need to free the node ..but why is it not produing the node deleted result when display is called second time..

Is there something to do with functions scope of  pointer variabe of type node q and the globally delcared start pointer of type node.

But actually i am tring to assign the start pointer value to q each time if i am calling delete without calling create..

Is there a replica of the linked list created by q without affecting the linked structure of node pointed by q.

Why is the nodes linked structure not getting changed when i try the code   `q->link=q->link->link;`  in the afore-mentioned place even when display() function  is called second time

Why do i need a secondary variable tmp;

I tried the above part .. it will print the first created list itself when i call the display function second time  `q->link=q->link->link` is not working when we are trying to display in second call...
This my linked list
60  0x557a152a2340
50  0x557a152a2320
40  0x557a152a2300
30  0x557a152a22e0
20  0x557a152a22c0
10  0x557a152a22a0

Can anyone please helpme by give  more resource material on how this tmp variable is working and what is the  peculiarity of pointer q ,pointer start and all

I will be greateful to any small help..

Comment: thanks Tom Karzes ..It works fine now ..I was confused withits working ..can you give me some quality resources on how this works internally like functions scope .. pointers and all thanks in advance

Comment: can you please give me a broad explanation on what happens when i do tmp=q->link . ..  actually tmp->link is null ...right .. how come it is same as q->link->link  .Totally confused there ...

Comment: Please apply some proper formatting to your code to make it readable. Also, if you eliminate `tmp` variable, what exactly do you feed into `free` function in the next line?

Comment: @Grehanb thanks for poining that out ..will do it

Comment: @Midhun - There is nothing magic going on. It is just that you need to follow the link to the next element, and then (only then!) delete the old one. Perhaps if `tmp` was called `old_node` it would be more obvious what happens?

Comment: Sidenote: Not specifying a return type for your function implicitely defines it as returning `int`. Your `return;` statements don't return a value. You should get some some compiler warnings. Also for implicit int declaration itself you should get some warning as this is a featuie from previous centuries

Comment: @Gerhardh  Actually i was confused with understanding tmp=q->link; q->link=tmp->link; is same as q->link=q->link->link;  ..Tom pointed out that ...so i am now getting a narrow idea ..can you sustantiate this explanation with more resourses on this statement ...Thanks Grehardh in advance

Comment: You did not answer my question: What do you put into `free` function call if you removed `tmp`? The assignment to `q->link = ...` will yield the same result no matter if you use `tmp` or not. This part is not the difference.